# Scrolling UITableView horizontally and Vertically

Tags: swift

when I embed UITableView within Scroll View it scrolls vertically but overwriting occurs while scrolling what to do...?

Comment: please provide some code of what you have tried

Comment: why are you embedding table view in scroll view. By default, table view provides scroll feature if your rows exceed your data container size.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

There is no need to embed UITableView within UIScrollView since UITableView is inherited from UIScrollView.
If you want horizontal scrolling you should use UICollectionView instead.

**Apple:**

*You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.*